# jquery crossdomain ajax and getJason return error

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

Hello I am trying to make an ajax call with jQuery as per the following instructions: http://data.hud.gov/housing_counseling.html

But since this is a crossdomain request, I need to do jsonp (not knowledgeable about it)

After research I've done the call in two ways, and I keep getting an error and the data is somewhere in the browser but I don;t know how to access it.

Note the callback parameters on the url (if I don't include it I get the Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. )

First call:

```
function loadJson() 
    {
        var statesurl = "http://data.hud.gov/Housing_Counselor/search?AgencyName=&City=&State=CA&jsoncallback=?"
        $.getJSON(statesurl, null, function(result){


        }).done(function(result) {

            var items = [];
            $.each( result, function( key, val ) {
                items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
                console.log(key + ": " + val)
            });

            $( "<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join( "" )
            }).appendTo( "div#thestates" ); 

        }).fail(function() {
            console.log( "error" );
        })
    }

$( "#loadstates" ).click(function() { loadJson()});
```

And I get a random callback name for the *callback* parameter, like http://data.hud.gov/Housing_Counselor/search?AgencyName=&City=&State=CA&jsoncallback=jQuery19107074434771202505_1384407999935&_=1384407999936  Via Chrome's console I can see the response is JSON data with pairs of key values.

[image]

Same thing happens with $.ajax call if I try the call with $.ajax:

```
function loadJsonP() 
{
    var statesurl = "http://data.hud.gov/Housing_Counselor/search?AgencyName=&City=&State=CA&jsoncallback=?"
    $.ajax({
        url:statesurl,
        dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
        success:function(json){
             // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
             console.log(json_encode(json))
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log("Error");
        },
    });
}
```

I get a similar response as the one illustrated above. Although for both the console.log output is "Error" but I see a 200 response

[image]

How should I handle the response to get a successful response and manipulate the JSON data, which clearly is somewhere in the browser

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER

The problem I was experiencing was caused by my browser's restrictions (I knew that, but to develop my answer I feel I must clarify this fact), which prevents loading content from another domain via ajax ( i.e., cross domain request ).

For a good and easy explanation of cross domain ajax limitations you can read this excellent article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Expose-Header

I thought I was getting data, and I though it was somewhere in my browser. I was not getting the data, I was seeing the content of the webpage that I was redirected from the responding server. If I have not explain this clearly, never mind, move on.

To make this work, I have to work with 3 files, the html where I trigger the ajax call, the js file where I had the script, and (VIP) the file that makes the request and formats the request to meet $.ajax() specs (I am working with PHP)

javascript file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    if (!(window.jQuery)) {  
        console.log('JQUERY NOT LOADED');
    }

    function loadJsonP(parametrizedurl) 
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "cors.php?" + parametrizedurl, // notice I will call a file in my own domain, and append the parametrized url as per API specs
            dataType: 'jsonp',  // data type jsonp (i.e., padded json)
            jsonp: 'jsonp_callback', // jsonp_callback is part of the parametrizedurl, and when it gets passed on the url, a random function is generated and appended. You would see something similar to this jQuery19103874713401310146_1385178790322
            complete: function(var_x){

                console.log('COMPLETE');
                console.log(this);
                console.log(var_x);

            },          
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('SUCCESS');
                console.log(data);
                $("#thestates").append(data);               
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                console.log('ERROR');
                console.log('textStatus: ' + textStatus);
                console.log('xhr: ' + xhr);
                console.log('errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);

            }
        });
    }

    $( "#loadstates" ).click(function() {

        var bystate = "url=http://data.hud.gov/Housing_Counselor/search&AgencyName=&City=&State=CA&jsonp_callback="  // notice I included the parameter jsonp_callback and left the value empty

        loadJsonP(bystate);

    });

});
```

This file is called by this html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Cross Domain Ajax Call</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="cfpb.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv"><h2>Generate a List</h2></div>
        <button type="button" value="Submit" id="loadstates">Load</button>
        <div id="thestates"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I execute click the button, the ajax call is made to cors.php file on my own server:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET)){

        $theurl = $_GET['url'].'/?';
        array_shift($_GET); // I remove the url parameter to easily create the parameter part of the url 

        $theurl .= http_build_query ($_GET); 

        $fhandle = fopen($theurl, 'r'); // I begin to read each line served to me by the API
        $data = array();

        $i = 0;         
        while(($buffer = fgets($fhandle)) !== false)
        {
            $temparray = explode(';',$buffer);
            $data[$i] = $temparray;
            $i++;
        }

        fclose($fhandle);

        $data = json_encode($data);

        echo $_GET['jsonp_callback']."(".$data.")"; // this results in the formatted json data PADDED (i.e., jsonp) by the autogenerated jsonp_callback value by the brower (i.e., jQuery19103874713401310146_1385178790322) 

    }

?>
```

In this example I can see the array of data trough Chrome's console and inserted into the page div#thestates

[image]